# youtube playlist video change

Tags: youtube-api

I am needing to have some info passed to scripts when **onPlayerStateChange()** function fires off.

What I am after is the current **videoID** of the currently playing video and the **array position** number from the playlist.

(-_-)ZZZzzz...

> ---

EDIT....

Ok. So I have progressed a bit.
In the player code, I have this fire off

```
    if (event.data == -1) {
      getPlaylistIndex();
    }
```

I then have this script.

```
function getPlaylistIndex() {
      var str = ""+ytplayer.getPlaylist();  
      var viedoString = str.split(',');
      var videoID = viedoString[ytplayer.getPlaylistIndex()];
   if(videoID == undefined){

   } else {
      alert(videoID);
        loadComents(videoID);
        loadVideoINFO(videoID);
   }
}
```

You will notice an IF condition which is needed to not fire the code for normal videos... just on the PL's.
It is working apart from the fact that when I load the playlist in, I do not get a videoID from the script. If I select any video in the playlist and also go back to the first one, it works fine. Just not working when first loading the playlist.

Any ideas ?
P.S.   the alert is for testing only.

> ---

RE-EDIT.... **;P**

Ok. I have been playing with this for the whole day going in and out of all scripts.
I have it working now (so it seems).

First I added into my code to give me this.

```
function getPlaylistIndex() {
      var str = ""+ytplayer.getPlaylist();  
      var viedoString = str.split(',');
      var videoID = viedoString[ytplayer.getPlaylistIndex()];
   if(videoID == undefined){

   } else {
            if(videoID == ''){
              var str2 = ytplayer.getVideoUrl();
              videoID = (str2.substring(31,42));
            }
    loadComents(videoID);
    loadVideoINFO(videoID);
   }
}
```

And so it works first time, I needed to change

**event.data == -1** to **event.data == 1** as YTplayer fires them in a particular order.

If anyone has anything to ad or correct, please do so.